# JS How to keep counting the time

Tags: javascript

I just started learning Javascript a month ago. I would like to know how to keep counting and updating and showing it in real-time.

```
 var date = new Date();
var second = document.querySelector('#sec')
var time = document.querySelector('#future-time')
function currentTime(){
  console.log('a')
  time.innerHTML = date;  
second.innerHTML = date.getSeconds();
}
  
setInterval(currentTime, 1000);
```

with this code, I can see the time on the page but then, the second doesn't update so it keeps saying the same second with `console.log()`. The current time on the page doesn't go forward. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running in to is that once you assign `var date = new Date()` then `date` will always be the datetime as of that exact time it was assigned. You can instead create a new Date object each time you call `currentTime` and you'll get a refreshed Date object current as of the time the function is called.

```js
var second = document.querySelector('#sec')
var time = document.querySelector('#future-time')
function currentTime(){
  var date = new Date();
  time.innerHTML = date;  
  second.innerHTML = date.getSeconds();
}
  
setInterval(currentTime, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="sec"></span>
<span id="future-time"></span>
```

Comment: Oh I see!! It’s all good now! Thank you so much!!